# Dockerized Flask app cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to setup a docker-compose file that creates 2 services i.e., the MySQL 8 service and a Flask app written python. Since I am using Mac M1, I am forced to use [arm64v8/mysql](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/mysql/)

The structure of the docker-compose file looks similar to this:

```
networks:
  app_network:
    external: false
    driver: bridge

services:

  ### API Container
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "9005:9005"
    networks:
      - app_network
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure


  ### MySQL Container
  db:
    container_name: app_db
    build:
      context: ./docker/db/
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
      - "33060:33060"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_REMOTE_HOST=${MYSQL_REMOTE_HOST}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

The dockerfile for MySQL service looks like

```
FROM arm64v8/mysql

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/
COPY my.cnf /etc/

ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_PORT
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_REMOTE_HOST

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
ENV MYSQL_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
ENV MYSQL_REMOTE_HOST=${MYSQL_REMOTE_HOST}
```

The environment variables are loaded from a .env file present in the same directory as the docker-compose script.
The problem now is that I am getting *sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")*

How do I fix this issue?

Note:
I am using the following versions:

Flask==2.2.2

Python==3.8

MySQL==8

MacOS==13.2.1

I tried to include the my.cnf file to change the bind address to accept remote connections

Comment: What is the database connection URL configured in your flask app?

Comment: Your database connection string in your Flask app specifies `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the address of the database. It needs to be `db`.

Comment: The DB connection string is 'mysql+pymysql://<app_user>:<user_pwd>@app_db:3308/<name_of_db_schema>'

Comment: If that's the case, then your app isn't using the connection string. The error message says that it can't connect to a database at 127.0.0.1 which is `localhost`. Since your connection string states that it should use `app_db` then it looks like the connection string isn't being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you state that your database connection string points to port 3308. That's not correct, since the MySQL database listens (unless configured otherwise, which you don't seem to have) on port 3306, not 3308.

The port 3308 that you mapped in your docker-compose.yml only has effect for communication from outside the docker-compose network; containers inside the network can't see these mapped ports.

Exposing the port of your MySQL container is also unnecessary, as long as you don't want to access the MySQL database from outside the docker-compose network.